# Confusion about vector projection within text.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projection

From the text "*Mathematical tools for applied multivariate analysis*", page 113, there's an example of rotating axis and vectors. I don't understand how they've got the results from projecting the $e_i$ (standard basis vectors) onto the $f_i$ vectors (rotation of $e_i$).

Here's the diagram of the rotation:

[image]

Which shows we have $f_1' = (0.867 , 0.5)$, and $f_2' = ( -0.5, 0.867)$

Later in the text they state the following:

[image]

I don't see how this result is found though, if I try and project `e1 -> f1` then I have:

```
e1 = (1, 0)
f1 = (0.867, 0.5)
theta = angle between f1 and e1

proj(e1 -> f1) = [ ( e1 . f1 ) / |f1|^2 ] . f1
               = [ ( e1 . f1 ) / 1      ] . f1
               = [ ( 0.867   )          ] . (0.867 0.5)
               = (0.867^2 , 0.867 * 0.5)
               = (.751, .43)
```

I'm clearly missing something obvious when projecting `e1` onto `f1`, but I'm not sure what.

I can see that we'd move `f1` by `-0.5` units along the `f2` axis to have it line up with `e1`, and that's where the numbers for $g_i$ come from, I just don't see how they've done the computation for them here.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not quite sure why you wrote $f_1'$ and $f_2'$ with the primes.

Second, you're misinterpreting what $g_1$ and $g_2$ are. When we write $e_1=af_1+bf_2$, then $g_1=\left[\begin{matrix} a \\ b\end{matrix}\right]$, and similarly for $g_2$. Of course, $a=e_1\cdot f_1$ and $b=e_1\cdot f_2$.

Last, let me say that this is the most cluttered diagram I've seen in anything resembling a presentation of basic linear algebra.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that they were saying to project `e1` onto `f1`, and `e2` onto `f2`. Are you saying that I was wrong to interpret it as that? What confused me was them saying to project ei -> fi, and it not working.